# how to update background normal property in kivy when using screenmanager

Tags: mobile, kivy

I'm making a multi-screen game in Kivy. On the main screen we have a set of buttons that each have their background normal property set to a png image. Each of the buttons leads to a separate screen where the user answers a question. Once the question is answered, the question screen leads the user back to the main screen. What we'd like to do is update the color of the button (using a different png file as background) to indicate to the user that a question has been answered.

Right now we've created a method in the main screen that changes the background color when a question in the background screen is answered correctly. By printing to the terminal we have been able to confirm that the color has been changed. However, when the app goes back to the main screen the color has not been changed. We think this is because the main screen is being reset when the user returns to it. What is the right approach to make the color of the button on the main screen not only conditional on a question being answered on a separate screen, but also permanent?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have the right general idea, but it isn't clear why your own change is not persistent. Could you post a simple example demonstrating what you think should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ScreenManager` keep a reference to the button that was pressed with `root.question`. You can access that from the screen. You can use you own images or the attached ones.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_string("""
<MyScreenManager>
    Screen:
        name: 'questionary'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Question 1'
                on_press: root.question = self; root.current = 'question_1'
                background_normal: 'answered.png'
            Button:
                text: 'Question 2'
                on_press: root.question = self; root.current = 'question_1'
                background_normal: 'answered.png'
    Screen:
        name: 'question_1'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Are you going to answer this question?'
            Button:
                text: 'Yes'
                on_press: root.question.background_normal = 'not_answered.png'; root.current = 'questionary'
""")


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image: answered]
[image: not_answered.jpg]

Comment: Thanks toto_tico! This is exactly what we were looking for